# difficulty based time estimation software

Tags: project-management, time-estimation

Some months ago I found a project-management / time-estimation software that would ask you to **sort out your tasks in terms of difficulty (1, 2 or 3)** and would then estimate the time you would take to deploy.

The system would auto-adapt as you were working.

I've forgot the software name. For the past days I've been digging emails and searching Google with no results.

Can anyone **pin the software name by my description**?

Its not http://www.fogcreek.com (though I've found it to be a great piece of software.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost a year and 1/2 I've found the exact same page I had seen the day before asking this question.

All in all what I saw was **[LiquidPlanners](http://www.liquidplanner.com/help/key-concepts/estimating-in-ranges.html) estimation in ranges** and, probably during sleep, I've come to think of it as something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be ["Construx Estimate"](http://www.construx.com/Page.aspx?nid=68) from Steve McConnell?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've put up a paper by my monitor saying, bookmark whatever you find interesting. ALWAYS.

Answer (score 1):

How about a software that would allow you to estimate a commitment date (by when you think you will deliver on a request) and communicate the date to the requester? As you work on your tasks the date re-calculates and if it slips you communicate a new commitment date so the requester could plan his work accordingly.

This is a tool we're working on, if you want to give it a try (it is in beta though):
http://yoxel.com/personal-commitment-manager.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be this by any chance would it ...

http://www.supermemo.com/help/taskman.htm

Comment: nope. But thank you! The program was web-based. This one is also a nice one, thanks. All in all we may well have to re-invent the wheel on this one and re-do it from scratch. I'm still searching and haven't found it either.